# Get everything between two strings using regexp_substr

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I would like to write a query that gets everything between two strings
So for example getting everything between utm_source and the '&' sign. This is what I have tried:

```
select regexp_substr(full_utm,'%utm_source%','%&%') from db
```

However this is invalid syntax

Here is a sample of what I am trying to extract

```
?utm_source=Facebook&utm_medium=CPC&utm_campaign=April+LAL+-+All+SA+-+CAP+250&utm_content=01noprice
```

I have also tried this

```
regexp_substr(full_utm, 'utm_source=(.*)&',1)
```

but this returns this:

```
utm_source=Facebook&utm_medium=CPC&utm_campaign=April+LAL+-+All+SA+-+CAP+250&
```

I've also using split_part:

```
select split_part(split_part(full_utm,'%utm_source=%',1),'&',1)
```

The problem is this returns both sources and campaign (e.g utm_campaign=xyz)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_replace()` instead:

```
select regexp_replace(full_utm, '.*utm_source=(.*)&.*', '\1')
from (select '?utm_source=Facebook&utm_medium=CPC&utm_campaign=April+LAL+-+All+SA+-+CAP+250&utm_content=01noprice' as full_utm from dual) x;
```